# aggregated sum based on keys in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object that looks like this

```
var data = [];
    data[0] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.UK.London',    'EU.UK.London':5, 'EU.UK.Bath':4, 'EU.France.Lyon':1,  'EU.France.Paris':0,  'Asia.Japan.Tokyo':4},
    data[1] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.UK.Bath',      'EU.UK.London':7, 'EU.UK.Bath':1, 'EU.France.Lyon':8,  'EU.France.Paris':0,  'Asia.Japan.Tokyo':1},
    data[2] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France.Paris', 'EU.UK.London':2, 'EU.UK.Bath':2, 'EU.France.Lyon':2,  'EU.France.Paris':6,  'Asia.Japan.Tokyo':3},
    data[3] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France.Lyon',  'EU.UK.London':9, 'EU.UK.Bath':0, 'EU.France.Lyon':1,  'EU.France.Paris':0,  'Asia.Japan.Tokyo':2},
    data[4] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France.Lyon',  'EU.UK.London':2, 'EU.UK.Bath':4, 'EU.France.Lyon':3,  'EU.France.Paris':7,  'Asia.Japan.Tokyo':7},
```

I would like to

- apply a function to the keys of my objects in my data so I can remove dot separated strings. So for example remove `London` or `UK.London` from `EU.UK.London` but not `UK` from `UK.London` or from `EU.UK.London`. *(Added after a comment by  T.J. Crowder below: to avoid confusion, you remove going backwards)*
- Then, for each object to take the aggregated sum grouped by the key

For instance if I strip the city, the last bit in the key strings, i want to end up with an array

```
 var data = [];
    data[0] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.UK',     'EU.UK':9, 'EU.France':1,  'Asia.Japan':4},
    data[1] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.UK',     'EU.UK':8, 'EU.France':8,  'Asia.Japan':1},
    data[2] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France', 'EU.UK':4, 'EU.France':8,  'Asia.Japan':3},
    data[3] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France', 'EU.UK':9, 'EU.France':1,  'Asia.Japan':2},
    data[4] = {'TrueDestination': 'EU.France', 'EU.UK':6, 'EU.France':10, 'Asia.Japan':7},
```

I have written this to strip the keys

```
    function stripper(d, k){
    // k controls how many times you want to strip the string
    for (i=0; i<k; ++i){
        if (d.lastIndexOf('.') > 0){
            d = d.substring(0, d.lastIndexOf('.'))
        }
    }
    return d
   }
```

but my function to work on the keys is a real embarrassment. (and it doesnt work!) Anyways, this is where I am so far

```
        stripLevel = 1
    columnNames = data.columns.map(d => stripper(d, stripLevel))

    for (j=0; j<columnNames.length; ++j){
            cname = columnNames[j];
            for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
                var _obj = {}
                obj = data[i]
                _keys = Object.keys(obj)
                total = 0
                for (k = 0; k < _keys.length; ++k) {
                    cur = _keys[k]
                    if ((cname != 'model_class') && (stripper(cur, stripLevel) === cname)) {
                        total += parseFloat(obj[cur])
                    }
                    _objTemp = {[stripper(cur, stripLevel)]: total}
                    Object.assign(_obj, _objTemp)
                    total = 0
                }
            }
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: *"apply a function to the keys of my objects in my data so I can remove dot separated strings. So for example remove London or UK.London from EU.UK.London but not UK from UK.London or from EU.UK.London"* What are the rules for deciding what does or doesn't get removed? The rules seem...odd...

Comment: *"...but not UK from UK.London or from EU.UK.London..."* Should it **add** `EU` to `UK.London` somehow? If so, how?

Comment: Lets say you remove going backwards, from the end to the beginning. Or if that makes it clearer you remove first the city and then the country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create new object and add the values of the same key.

It works with the entries of the object and the destructured key/value pair `k`/`v` and a function for getting the first parts of the dotted strings and a check of the key.

If the key `k` is equal to `TrueDestination`, then it takes the unchanged key and assigns the changed value to it. in all other cases, it takes the value of the property with the new key or zero, adds the value and assign the sum to the property.

Finally the object is returned.

```js
var data = [{ TrueDestination: 'EU.UK.London', 'EU.UK.London': 5, 'EU.UK.Bath': 4, 'EU.France.Lyon': 1, 'EU.France.Paris': 0, 'Asia.Japan.Tokyo': 4 }, { TrueDestination: 'EU.UK.Bath', 'EU.UK.London': 7, 'EU.UK.Bath': 1, 'EU.France.Lyon': 8, 'EU.France.Paris': 0, 'Asia.Japan.Tokyo': 1 }, { TrueDestination: 'EU.France.Paris', 'EU.UK.London': 2, 'EU.UK.Bath': 2, 'EU.France.Lyon': 2, 'EU.France.Paris': 6, 'Asia.Japan.Tokyo': 3 }, { TrueDestination: 'EU.France.Lyon', 'EU.UK.London': 9, 'EU.UK.Bath': 0, 'EU.France.Lyon': 1, 'EU.France.Paris': 0, 'Asia.Japan.Tokyo': 2 }, { TrueDestination: 'EU.France.Lyon', 'EU.UK.London': 2, 'EU.UK.Bath': 4, 'EU.France.Lyon': 3, 'EU.France.Paris': 7, 'Asia.Japan.Tokyo': 7 }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.entries(o).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
        const firsts = k => k.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
        if (k === 'TrueDestination') {
            o[k] = firsts(v);
        } else {
            k = firsts(k);
            o[k] = (o[k] || 0) + v;
        }
        return o;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina, that works like a charm. Can you briefly describe how that works please? I try to get my head around map reduce but havent managed to  get the grip of it....

Comment: Do you also think, that something like this can be used to calc the median instead of the sum please? It will require I imagine to somehow collect all the values in an array maybe and at the end to sort them and pick the midpoint. I am not asking you to write this, just if you think it is doable and a hint of how one should proceed. Thanks again!

Comment: for the median, you need an array and finally pick a value or an average of the middle values of the sorted array. for an average, you need a sum and a count and finally take the result of the division. in tis case, you have a two step iteration, one over the objects and the other over key/values. after the key/value iteration, you could return the wanted median (really?) or the average.

Comment: Thanks a million Nina, all the best!